# How to split large txt file into small txt files using startswith in python?

Tags: python

i have a text file with this pattern

a.txt

```
61000001
11111111
22222222
61000002
11111111
22222222
33333333
61000003
11111111
22222222
33333333
```

i want to split to multiple txt file using startswith in python like this. How to do it? Thanks.

61000001.txt

```
11111111
22222222
```

61000002.txt

```
11111111
22222222
33333333
```

61000003.txt

```
11111111
22222222
33333333
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you tried writing code? If so, please share a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: Is `61000001` supposed to be in the first file? Could you share the code you have attempted thus far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read your all content of the file with the following code:

```
File_object = open(r"a.txt","r")
contents = File_object.read().splitlines()
print(contents)
```

Now you have all content of the file in a variable, you can split it with the following code:

```
file = None
prefix = "61000"
for content in contents:
    if content.startswith(prefix):
        filename = content+".txt"
        file = open(filename,"w")

    file.write(content+"\n")
```

Don't forget exception handling and closing file in each iteration of loop.

Comment: And don't forget to close.

Answer (score 1):

This produces the files in your post from a.txt

```
with open('a.txt', 'r') as fin:
  prefix = "6100000"
  output = []
  for line in fin:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith(prefix):  # Check for prefix
      if output:
        with open(line + '.txt', 'w') as out:
          out.write('\n'.join(output))
          print(output)
          output = []
    output.append(line)
  if output:                     # last file for residual data
      with open(line + '.txt', 'w') as out:
          out.write('\n'.join(output))
```